# Nilpotent completion of a free group

Tags: group-theory, reference-request

Let $F$ be the free group on $m$-generators ($m\geq 2$).

Denote the $k$-th lower central subgroup of $F$ by $F_k$.

(That is, $F_0=F$ and $F_{r+1}=[F_r,F]$.)

Then, using the inverse system consists of the quotient maps,
\begin{equation}\cdots\to F/F_3\to F/F_2\to F/F_1\end{equation}

we can define the nilpotent completion of $F$, $\bar{F}=\lim F/F_n$.

I saw many papers saying that $\bar{F}$ is an uncountable group.

Where is the proof of this statement?

Comment: I think that a way to show this is to prove that $\bar{F}$ is a profinite group, since every profinite group is finite or uncountably infinite.

Comment: Or if you look at the definition of the inverse limit as a subgroup of a free product, it seems fairly clear that this is uncountable, because for each element of $F/F_k$ there is more than one element of $F/F_{k+1}$ that maps onto it.